# Jenkinsfile stage trigger based on conditions

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Need to trigger a stage only when the Static_Check Parameter is selected

```
Parameter: Name: Static_Check ; Type: Checkbox


stage ('Static_Check') {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find an answer in my [blog post on conditionals in Jenkins pipelines](https://medium.com/@MichaKutz/conditionals-in-a-declarative-pipeline-jenkinsfile-d1a4a44e93bb).